# Image in center of div unknown height width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to center an image using [CSS Trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/). But what if the image size will be random(not-fixed). Surprisingly I don't want to keep image responsive, I want to bring image in center without changing its width or height(actual pixel).

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider"><img class="center" src="images/mySlide.jpg" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
       width: 100%;
       position: relative;
}
.center {
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%; 
       margin-left: -150px;
       margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can center any image like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/y5vh3/2/

```
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
}
.slider:before
{
    height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content:"";
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

With such HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img class="center" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x40" />
</div>
```

Comment: Elegant. Like it. Can you explain what the essential property/ values are and why they're important?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dewd the most important part is the `inline-block` and the `:before` (could also be :after) pseudo element. You can have two `inline-block` elements be centered vertically, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/xv76s/ We fake a element with the height of the parent contaner and we can center our image against this element, like in the demo.