# vertical-align: middle; div in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, vertical-alignment

With a grid of boxes that vary in size, one of the boxes has a bootstrap carousel: http://www.bootply.com/129530

Have tried a bunch of combinations for getting the text of the items in the carousel to be vertically aligned in the middle.

For the technique that makes the most sense, *the text disappeared from the page!?*

```
<div class="box10 border">
  <div class="questions">
    <div id="questions-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="middleContainer">
            <div class="middle">
              <div class="question">...text here...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div><!-- /item -->
        <div class="item">
          <div class="middleContainer">
            <div class="middle">
              <div class="question">...text here...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /item -->
      </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->
    </div><!-- /carousel -->
  </div><!-- /questions -->
</div><!-- /box10 -->
```

Here's the css, this is using the relative + absolute table 100% + table-cell 50% vertical-align technique:

```
.box10 {
  height:20%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.questions {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.middleContainer {
  position: relative;
}
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.question {
  height: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't vertically align text in its container without either:

- using flexbox
- fixing the height of the text container
- limiting the text to one line only

Each of those "solution" has their downside so you have to make a compromise..
For example, with Flexbox you loose some browser support as you can see here: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: understandable.. though, what are the downsides to a flexbox with these circumstances?

Comment: Thanks for the support mention.. Am cool with that.. Would definitely appreciate a flexbox solution if you have one in mind..

Comment: I answered your other question about flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can extend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427173/image-in-center-of-div-unknown-height-width/22427321#22427321) to match your needs.

```
.questions:after {
    content: "";
    height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.carousel {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```